# Canon battery life indicator not working?

Tags: troubleshooting

I’ve purchased a canon 800D/t7i about 3 weeks ago now, and for the first charge of the battery everything worked well. Now however the battery life indicator seems to just be stuck at full battery at all times, even when it’s about to die completely, it will shut off abruptly still showing full bars of battery. There’s no warning or sudden drop down to one battery bar that flashes red at you, it just switches off with full battery bars.

I’ve tried resetting the settings numerous times and no new firmware for the camera has been released by Canon. Do you guys have any suggestions? I’ve contacted the retailer but they seem very hesitant to provide me with any exchange or refund and keep telling me to send it in for repair under warranty but would like to avoid this if possible as they’re known to take forever to repair it and send it back.

Comment: Do you buy a "kit" where the seller threw in a bunch of cheap crap? And probably swapped the real Canon battery out for a third party battery?

Comment: Not all cheap batteries are crap. I bought about a dozen, and many are better than the original - after five years of usage - and some are worthless crap after a week. You never know. But they cost a tenth of the original, so just get three different ones.

Comment: I use Baxxtar batteries, 1/3 the price of the true Canon ones, and work just as well (and better than the fake Canon batteries).

Answer (score 2):

It could be a problem wit the battery. You can get a second one, Canon or good OEM, and see If it has the same problem. If not, then it was the first battery, and you just bought a  replacement (batteries are consumables). Otherwise it's the camera, and you are left with an always useful spare battery.

Answer (score 1):

This happens. From my experience of working with batteries from sony to canon etc., these things will happen at some point. Some batteries last for years and don't show a sign of obsolescence, some batteries won't work after a few weeks. It depends on how heavy these batteries are used and how you treat them. Humidity, Heat, Cold, direct sunlight etc. should be avoided.

Buying a new battery is probably your best bet as I wouldn't bother trying to fix it.